# Why is the edit queue always full?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I am quite active on the rsyslog tag on Stack Overflow - and as it seems almost the only one. Even though a lot of questions there aren't programming related, I think it's important that the questions still get answered, as a lot of people don't know the Stack Exchange Network and thus only post their questions here.

Now the tag isn't one which is used much - an average of 2-3 questions per week - but still the edit queues are almost always full. If it happens that I can request an edit, most of the time it gets accepted very quick (in a few hours). But I (very) rarely see an edit of an other person.

Why are the edit queues always full then? Sometimes it's even if there have only been 5 people who have seen the question. But in the end, I never (or very very rarely) see a question that has been edited.

Comment: there arent edit queues for _each tag_... SO gets a _lot_ of questions. There is one queue for the site. So you may not see suggested edits in your tag but they exist for others

Comment: *"Why is the edit queue always full?"* In my opinion, the short answer: too many people submit low quality edits and not enough people (myself including) go through the review queue (peer reviewing low quality edits over and over again can be a real motivation killer).

Comment: @SurajRao Oh okay, I didn't know that. But i guess it makes sense - especially for tags with a smaller audience.

Comment: @Larnu Well that's understandable and I respect and appreciate the people who use their time to review these posts, as i think (or guess) it isn't the most fulfilling work to do. But as I just read, it isn't a tag specific but a general problem that Stack Overflow is facing.

Comment: As mentioned, @eDonkey , the edit queue is site wide not tag. If there were (say) 500 pending edits and *every single one* were on a post tagged [[tag:python]] then those when < 2,000 reputation could not submit an edit on *anything*; regardless of the post type or its tags.

Comment: A bit unrelated directly to the question asked here, but this phrase is really wrong (although your intentions are probably good) - *"Even though a lot of questions there aren't programming related, I think it's important that the questions still get answered, as a lot of people don't know the Stack Exchange Network and thus only post their questions here"*. Just because people don't know the SE network doesn't mean we should keep off-topic questions. If there is another, more suitable site, you should direct those users to it and flag/close the questions as off-topic - not answer them...

Comment: In fact, as @Tomerikoo noted, you've nearly answered your own question. The reason why the suggested edit queue is always full is because people are submitting edits to blatantly off-topic questions when they should be simply flagging them to be closed. Off-topic questions should not be edited; that just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I see that i am not only asking about the problem, but rather am part of the problem. I've got to say, that sometimes i'm just not sure where a question really belongs, as e.g. configs could be seen as "programming" as they often use their own language... I guess I have to overthink about how I'll handle such questions in the future.

Comment: A lot of the poor questions could, with enough care and attention, be made acceptable, but the kicker is if the asker put in the time that the care and attention requires they probably wouldn't have a question left. A good question-asking process leads to solutions, and a lot of those solutions are self-discovered. It's kind of counter productive with respect to the Stack Overflow mission of gathering high quality questions, but good question writers ask very few questions because in the process of asking the question, they usually get the answer.

Comment: It's always full because pushing things into the queue is a source of rep, while getting things out of it isn't.

Comment: There is a single edit queue, and for an edit to be approved or declined, a lot of people with enough reputation have to vote on it, or a person with enough reputation to choose can just choose. There are too many edits and the edit queue gets too large that it gets full.

Comment: It's always full because there is too high a bar (in terms of reputation) for the privilege of reviewing edits.

Comment: @chb seeing what kind of edits are approved by some reviewers, I'd say the bar is too low.

Comment: I think stack overflow should recruit more people to check edits and also there are many edits because most of the questions are asked by new contributors who don’t know the features of SO like code blocks and snippets which results in people having to edit it.

Comment: @ArchitGargi The people making these mistakes *are* the future people who will be fixing them. There's always going to be more incoming than there are people to fix them.

Comment: @KevinB yeah they are but in present they are the ones who don’t read the articles before posting.

Comment: @KevinB indeed. On top of the fact that the queues are relatively undiscoverable in the first place, *what is supposed to be my incentive* for participating? I mean, personally I don't care about reputation any more, but if we're *taking for granted* that rep points are what motivate people here, then there's a clear incentive misalignment. Further, there's a constant trickle of questions on Meta implying that the review queues are a good way to end up getting unjustly rebuked or disciplined by the system through its "audits".

Comment: Although my answer is: the queue is always full *because there is a queue*. A site with ~20 million questions and ~20 million users gets hamstrung by a 500-long queue because the site wants people to cooperate to approve edits (and focus their attention on the same set of edits), when a lot of the same people doing the approval could just unilaterally make the edit themselves.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel My understanding is there is a lot of interest in making some... adjustments to that system in the future that very well can resolve that issue.... but change takes time.

Answer (score 3):

*This answer is not mine it is a summary of all the comments and is just so that if you are interested you don't have to read all the comments.*

There aren't edit queues for *each tag*, there is just one queue for the whole site. Therefore you may not see suggested edits in *your tag*, but they exist for others.

So, if there were (say) 500 pending edits and *every single one* were on a post tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) then those with < 2,000 reputation could not submit an edit on *anything*; regardless of the post type or its tags.

---

To keep the edit queue from *overflowing*, the main thing you should ask yourself before submitting an edit to a question is: **Is this an edit to an off-topic question? Is there another, more suitable site?**

If yes, direct those users to it and flag/close the questions as off-topic.